# Abs are built in the kitchen, but what about obliques and lower abs?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, abdominals

I've made some major changes as to what I cook within the kitchen, such as using Coconut Oil, substituting in sweet potatoes, etc.

But I've, as of so far, haven't seen much improvement/visibility in my lower abs and obliques.  Even though trimming body fat is essential to visibility, how can I make these certain abs stand out? I'm an active sprinter who also spends 20 minutes a day toning my abs with various exercises, including P90X ab-ripper and weighted workouts.

Any suggestions in the gym or food wise to make them really stand out? (By food, I mean food I should be consuming more of and food that I might not know has a surprising volume of fat).

Comment: @BenSewards that is no Problem, sometimes StackExchange might seem a bit harsh to get into, but it's worth it once you get used to it. I think the question might be worth reopening now, although it would help to know what activities you are already doing.

Comment: Be as specific as you can be, read some of the other questions to get a feeling for that.

Comment: @Informaficker good suggestion, will do

Comment: The idea that eating fat makes you fat is a myth. Dietary fat is not the same as body fat.

Comment: Even though I don't have a background in nutrition, I do understand that there are dietary fats that actually help. Once my question opens again, I would hope for some answers regarding food selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abs are actually built in the gym, to SEE a 6-pack you need to have a low body fat %:7 – 8% for men and 11 – 12% for women (estimates).  To get lean and to stay lean long term are two different endeavors and requires a lot of dedication.

Comment: Without the right food you will not reach this point, and I am sure that there are people out there who have never been to a gym but still have abs ;)

Comment: @Informaficker - everyone has abs (well, except for people that had them removed maybe) - it's strong abs and abs that you see. Strong abs are built in the gym or through hard work - abs that you see (the mighty 6-pack) are a result of low body fat

Comment: the gym is a substitute for people who don't do real hard work anymore, for most people they are built in the gym.

Comment: @RobinAshe that's rather vague. Also, I'm a web developer so "hard work" physical wise, isn't in my agenda until after work.